# Запятая перед "как". Сравнительный оборот

Tags: пунктуация, как, союзы

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, требуется ли запятая перед союзом "как" в следующем предложении:

"Изначально КОМПАНИЯ создавалась как сеть пиццерий в формате take away."

Или же союз "как" здесь имеет значение "в качестве"?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Изначально компания создавалась как сеть пиццерий в формате take away.

Оборот с союзом КАК не обособляется, так как имеет значение "в качестве", то есть является обстоятельством в основном сообщении.

Такие обороты обособляются, если имеют значение причины.

Comment: Большое спасибо Вам за ответ! Я нашла правило у Розенталя, но крепко сомневалась. Вы развеяли сомнения)).

Answer (score -2):

Нет, перед сравнениях запятая не нужна. Она нужна только прежде обстоятельствах.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?